# $.ajax jquery to php script that stores in mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have this code in jquery:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url:  "tosql.php",
  data: {textnode: textnode},
  success: function(){
    alert( "Data Saved: " );
  }
});
```

and this php script:

```
<?php
  $textnode = $_POST['textnode'];
  $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  if (!$con)
  {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
  mysql_select_db("repository", $con);

  mysql_query("INSERT INTO paragraphs (paragraphs) VALUES ('$textnode')");

  mysql_close($con);
?>
```

When I go to mysql to view if the array was stored, I see "Array" as the value. What I'm trying to do is store each value in the array into its own row also. Serialize didn't work in this case.

Comment: It is an array right? if var_dump, or print_r outputs multiple keys, then you will need to loop over the array, and run an insert on each iteration.  I'm not sure if you are asking to store the value and the key, and i'm not sure if the array is multidimensional. Rules will change a little if so.

Comment: its a simple array, not multidimensional. I'm just trying to store the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edited:

```
if(get_magic_quotes_gpc())
  $magic = 1;
else
  $magic = 0;


foreach($textnode as $key => $value) {

 if($magic == 0){
   $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $con);
 }
 else{
   $value = stripslashes($value);
   $value = mysql_real_escape_string($value, $con);
 }


 mysql_query("INSERT INTO paragraphs (paragraphs)
 VALUES ('$value')");


}
```

Comment: I should clarify. Im storing the outerHTML of <p> elements and I've only been able to get some of them into mysql. Would the serialize be required here?

Comment: I am no php expert, but in my own CMS, when I'm storing html, i just use mysql_real_escape_string();  Edited answer

Comment: Note: If magic_quotes_gpc is enabled, you will be escaping the data twice, and you will need to use the stripslashes function first.  see the man page here http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php

Comment: Well, what problems are you having exactly? What do you mean by "ive only been able to get some of them into mysql" Is it only grabbing parts of the <p elements, not getting attributes?  You should set up a test case, with jquery, to see what it is actually grabbing.

Comment: I have 29 <p> elements (with their html contents) stored in the array. MYSQL only shows 8 of them without stripslashes, with $value = stripslashes($value, $con); before mysql_real_escape_string....I see all 29 rows...but the html columns are all blank :(

Comment: the stripslashes function does not take a second parameter.  See updated answer, and try that. It would be helpful to see the structure of the array...

Comment: it works now ! :p stupid mistake on the second parameter. I have 5 windows open Thank you!